# How do I run Laravel websockets on Azure?

Tags: laravel, azure, websocket

I've currently got the basic Azure package and am trying to run my laravel application. I used to have my app running on Plesk where websockets worked fine.

I've currently gotten my app to run on azure, but haven't been able to do so on my azure app.

**Problem:**
When I try to run `php artisan websockets:serve` in the console it just times out.

**I've tried to:** increased the time out time but the command just shows a spinner that keeps spinning

**What I'm trying to achieve:** get laravel websockets running on Azure

*This is my first experience with azure.*

Comment: did you [enable websockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/deployment/using-signalr-with-azure-web-sites#websocket) on your web app?

Comment: Yes! Even restarted the webserver.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56764014/1561929

Comment: Do you have port 6001 open and available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by not using the Azure web app service, but he VMS. This allowed me to setup a virtual machine with plesk.

This allowed me to run websockets with my laravel app on my VMS.

Currently Azure web app service [doesn't support](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/blog/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites/) `php sockets`, Azure VMS does

**Steps I took**

Laravel install Azure VMS

1. Install Ubuntu server 18
2. Install Plesk (https://get.plesk.com/)
3. Connect domain trough name server
4. Add GitHub repository
5. Install php version (https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-and-configure-php-70-or-php-71-on-ubuntu-16-04)
6. Install laravel dep. “composer global require laravel/installer”
7. Update dependancies “composer update”
8. Create Mysql Database
9. Add .env with settings
10. Install and configure supervisor for web sockets (https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/1.0/basic-usage/starting.html#using-a-different-port)
11. Additional steps to install web sockets ( https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/supervisor-configuration-could-not-open-input-file-artisan?page=0 )